# C++ Linked list - inserting node function doesn't update values out of function scope

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am writing a program that performs functions on a singly linked list containing nodes of the following structure:

```
typedef int ITEM;
typedef struct NODE* NODEptr;

struct NODE
{
    ITEM data;
    NODEptr next;
};
```

And this is the function I call to add a node to the head of the list (hdList points to the head of the list):

```
void addToHead(NODEptr &hdList, ITEM input)
{
    NODEptr newNode = new NODE; 
    newNode->data = input;
    newNode->next = nullptr;
    hdList = newNode; 
}
```

However I found whilst using the debugger that the value of hdList is not updated when the program leaves the function, even though it is being passed by reference, and I am not sure why.

Many thanks for your help and advice.

EDIT: As requested, full code here: http://pastebin.com/bLv0S2QG 
Also I am compiling with Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Looks like you should be setting `newNode->next` to `hdList` Just make sure `hdList` is initialized to `nullptr`.

Comment: @ooga Make this an answer!

Comment: Reserving ALL UPPERCASE for macros helps to avoid name collisions and inadvertent text substitution, and is also easier on the eyes and ears. As a matter of communicating well with maintainers of the code, saying T* is shorter and more clear than saying `typedef T* T_ptr` and then `T_ptr`.

Comment: Re "hdList is not updated", *if that is correct* then a **complete code example** is needed to diagnose it. Please do post such example. But anyway, note that if the function is called with a common start pointer as actual argument, then the function guarantees a list with exactly one node -- is that the intention?

Comment: Okay thanks I didn't know about the caps thing
Also the I was actually taught to do the typedefs to make it more readable but I see where you're coming from, perhaps I'll change it

Comment: It looks very C like, I know this isn't the question but you should use the `std::list` unless it's a H/W assignment. Also, the `struct` in your `typedef` is redundant in C++.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'm not quite sure what your question is - the function will add a node to a list of any size

Comment: @Cramer yes it's an assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct function will look as

```
void addToHead(NODEptr &hdList, ITEM input)
{
    NODEptr newNode = new NODE; 
    newNode->data = input;
    newNode->next = hdList;
    hdList = newNode; 
}
```

Or if your compiler supports the C++ 2011 then

```
void addToHead(NODEptr &hdList, ITEM input)
{
    NODEptr newNode = new NODE { input, hdList }; 
    hdList = newNode; 
}
```

Initially `hdList` has to be initialized by `nullptr` or `NULL`. For example

```
NODEptr hdList = nullptr;
```

Comment: "correct" depends on **how the function is called**: the code given in this answer can be wrong for the OP's calling pattern. which is why i asked the OP for a complete code example. for example, the function can be called with `hdlist` referring to the `next` pointer in the last node of the list, and with the OP's implementation that way of calling it would make sense and be correct.

Comment: Also note that the OP's claim "hdList is not updated" is not affected in any way by changing/fixing the linking of the list. So the OP is guaranteed wrong about either the problem description or the selection of this answer as a solution. Therefore it would help with explicitly stated assumptions in the answer, namely what is assumed about the calling of the function (and that the OP's claim is incorrect).

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf  ""correct" depends on how the function is called: the code given in this answer can be wrong for the OP's calling pattern. " The function is correct independing of how OP  calls it. There can be only invalid using of the function and nothing more.